# Xamarin Forms 5 - Android.Content.PM.Permission[] grantResults

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

Create a new default project and getting erros from MainActivity.cs

```
Error CS0234 ...namespace "Content" not exist in namespace "Xamarin.Android"
```

Missing somethings ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My fault I think, now are ok

```
...OnRequestPermissionsResult(... [GeneratedEnum] Permission[] grantResults)
```